# Read connected wallet RPC URL in Javascript

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, web3js, metamask, ethers.js

I wish my dApp users to trigger certain functions only if they are using MEV protection.
Can I check if the connected wallet is using a specific RPC URL? E.g. https://rpc.mevblocker.io connectes you to Ethereum mainnet behind a MEV blocker.